# Converting an edgelist to data.tree

Tags: r, dataframe, tree

I want to use the `data.tree` library in R to convert an edgelist to a tree object.

This is the code I have:

```
library(data.tree)

edges <- read.csv("data.csv")
colnames(edges) <- c("source", "target") 

R1 <- data.frame(Parent=edges$source, Child=edges$target)

R2<- data.frame(Parent=c("earth","earth","forest","forest","ocean","ocean","ocean","ocean"),
                           Child=c("ocean","forest","tree","sasquatch","fish","seaweed","mantis shrimp","sea monster"))
```

Now, if I run `tree <- FromDataFrameNetwork(R2)`, things work as they should. But if I do `tree <- FromDataFrameNetwork(R1)`, I get the following error:

```
Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
Error during wrapup: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
```

How can this be?

R1 looks like this:

```
  Parent Child
1      1     6
2      4     2
3      3     5
4      1     4
5      1     5
6      5     3
```

R2 looks like this:

```
  Parent         Child
1  earth         ocean
2  earth        forest
3 forest          tree
4 forest     sasquatch
5  ocean          fish
6  ocean       seaweed
7  ocean mantis shrimp
8  ocean   sea monster
```

Comment: In R1 3 is parent of 5 and 5 is parent of 3. How can this be in a tree?

Answer (score 0):

As @lukeA says, R1 contains a circular relationship. If 3 is a parent of 5 and 5 is a parent of 3, `FromDataFrameNetwork(R1)` will recurse infinitely while trying to build the tree. You could write a recursive helper function to validate the tables that you're trying to convert to a tree, such as:

```
library(tidyverse)

validate <- function(origin, tree, ancestors = character()){
  ancestors = c(ancestors, origin)

  kids <- tree %>%
    filter(Parent == origin) %>%
    select(Child) %>%
    pull()

  invalid.kids <- kids[kids %in% ancestors] # if any Child appears in its own ancestry, then it's invalid

  if(length(invalid.kids)){
    print(paste('invalid children:',
    paste(invalid.kids, collapse = ', '),
    'parent:',
    origin)) # print Children that produce circular relationships for debugging

  }

  children <- lapply(kids[!(kids %in% ancestors)], validate, tree, ancestors) # recursively apply validate() to all valid Children

  tree <- filter(tree, !(Child %in% invalid.kids)) # key step: filter out parts that would cause an infinite loop

  return(rbind(tree, do.call(rbind, children)))
}
```

Caution: I haven't tested this exact script, but I've used similar approaches in the past.